# How to rerun Tesseract OCR?

Tags: tesseract

Tesseract OCR is running on iOS 8.x, on an iPhone 5.
It typically does well on the first image (from camera),
but subsequently produces garbage (as the "recognized text").

I presume there is some kind of internal state in
the Tesseract library that needs to be cleared before
each re-run (i.e., same app instance, but for all OCR
runs after the first). Does anybody know off-hand what, if any,
special steps should be taken before a re-run of Tesseract?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call `api.Clear()` or `api.ClearAdaptiveClassifier()`.

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=935